# Changing classes in specific elements using coffeescript

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript, handlebars.js

```
ftemplate =  Handlebars.compile '''
    <div class="filter">
       <ul class="list">
           <li><a href="#" class="today active">Today</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" class="month">Month</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" class="year">Year</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>'''
```

I have a list where I want to add a class based on which element is clicked. The following is the coffeescript code I am using to to achieve that.

```
class exports.InfoController extends Backbone.View
  tagName: 'div'
  className : 'box'
  events:
    "click a.today" : "_filterTodayClicked"
    "click a.year" : "_filterYearClicked"
    "click a.month" : "_filterMonthClicked"

  _filterYearClicked: (e) =>
    e.preventDefault()
    @model.goToTimeFrame "year"

  _filterMonthClicked: (e) =>
    e.preventDefault()
    @model.goToTimeFrame "month"

  _filterTodayClicked: (e) =>
    e.preventDefault()
    @model.goToTimeFrame "day"
```

What I'm trying to do is to do reference this.parent and then cycle through all the  elements, removing the "active" class from each (if it exists) and then adding it to the element that is clicked. 
In pseudocode:

```
_filterYearClicked(e) =>
    e.preventDefault()
    (this).parent.('a').removeClass('active')
    (this).addClass('active)
```

The reason I cannot simply access the class 'list' and use that instead of this.parent is because there are a number of other lists (with the same class) also controlled by the same controller and I do not want to have the classes in other lists to be changed. I have tried searching for ways to do this online, but haven't found a working solution at all. Any help or links to useful documentation would be really appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at the event's [`currentTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) to figure out where you are, then [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) will get you back to the appropriate root and [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to come back down:

```
_filterYearClicked: (e) =>
  e.preventDefault()
  $t = $(e.currentTarget)
  $t.closest('ul').find('.active').removeClass('active')
  $t.addClass('active')  
  #...
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/rPLTU/ (only *Year* is hooked up)

Or you can use the view's [`$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el) to restrict your `.active` search to the current view:

```
_filterYearClicked: (e) =>
  e.preventDefault()
  @$el.find('.active').removeClass('active')
  $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active')
  #...
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/cHKUt/ (only *Year* is hooked up)